# In android app, Clear small icon in status bar when onResume method is called

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am developing android app with push notification.

I want to clear small icon in status bar that appeared by push notification, when onResume method is called.

Then, I write the following code ,however It does not work well.

※※PushHandlerActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    GCMIntentService.cancelNotification(this);
    finish();
}
```

※※GCMIntentService.java

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1234;
private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super("GCMIntentService");
}

public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
{
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String appName = getAppName(this);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
            .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    String message = extras.getString("message");
    if (message != null) {
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
    } else {
        mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
    }

    String msgcnt = extras.getString("msgcnt");
    if (msgcnt != null) {
        mBuilder.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(msgcnt));
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
}

public static void cancelNotification(Context context)
{
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.cancel((String)getAppName(context), NOTIFICATION_ID);  
}

private static String getAppName(Context context)
{
    CharSequence appName = 
            context
                .getPackageManager()
                .getApplicationLabel(context.getApplicationInfo());

    return (String)appName;
}
}
```

I would appreciate if you could tell me how to solve this problem.
I am stuck!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do it is to auto cancel the notification :

`.setAutoCancel(true)`

This would remove the notification automatically when it's tapped.

This is where you add it in your code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
        .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think your method is the one when notification is tapped. I'd like to know a method when the app is resumed. For instance; tapping the app icon on Home Screen. I would appreciate if you could tell me the above method.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID= 1234;
String NotiSer = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NotiSer);
mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

To cancel this notification :

```
mNotificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I am not good at java , because I am developing the app with phonegap. I would appreciate if you could tell me how to fix the above codes.

Comment: Where does the method getAppName come from? Are you sure, it returns the same String, if once called for GCMIntentService.java and once for PushHandlerActivity.java ?
I would at first try the NotificationManager methods, which do not take an additional tag (as proposed by Tony).
If that works, either hard-code the app-name, or make sure your method getAppName really returns the same in both cases.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I add the code of getAppName method. I would appreciate if you could tell me how to repair above codes.